# Android Camera Application, preview crash

Tags: android, camera

So I started with this little write-up.  I wanted to try to make an application that will take pictures while running in the background.   To start though I wanted an application that once opened would simply take a picture every X seconds.  After recreating the classes and methods show in the walk through below I ran into a few problems.

http://itp.nyu.edu/~sve204/mobilemedia_spring10/androidCamera101.pdf

For starters its seems that the onCreate function sets up all the objects for the application, but if you try to take a picture through any other method than onClick (IE directly calling it) the application actually hasn't setup the canvas or the preview yet.

My first question:
Is there any conditional method that you can setup that will wait till all the "onCreate" objects are created and their associated methods are called and finished?   How do I wait for the application to finish putting together my surface and starting the cameras preview before automatically starting to take pictures?

My second question: 
I am required to have a preview available to take pictures.  Is there anyway to push this application to the back (IE running in the background) while still taking pictures?  Is drawing to a canvas a requirement?  (From what I can tell AFAIK, you are required to have a surfaceholder to start preview, when you put up another screen or application that pauses the current application and closes the surface/canvas you were presenting that preview on).   If my understanding is correct on all of this the best I will be able to do is make a 1x1 pixel canvas that will still take up the screen due to the application being in the foreground.

My Third question: is there any way around this?  Can you still utilize the camera in some fashion without requiring the preview be drawn?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to implement `SurfaceHolder.Callback` and wait for it's `surfaceCreated()` to be called.

   After that you can do all `MediaRecorder` preparation (setPreviewDisplay,setAudio, setVideo, prepare()).
2. You can overlay SurfaceView with another view and thus hide it.